# PHP - Echo amount of pictures based on mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to code a script that will echo an amount of images based on the mysql_num_rows(); function.

Like, I'm storing 3 in a row. Then I'll create:

```
$images = mysql_num_rows($count);
```

Then I would like it to echo 3 images.

Is this possible? 
If you don't get the question or want me to rewrite it, please just tell me.

Comment: do you mean that based on the number of rows in the result set $Count, you want to display those many number of images? For .e.g. if $count contains 5 records then you want to display 5 images, is that right?

Comment: I have to use this for a small rating script, where I was thinking to store stars given as number from 1-5 in a row, and then echo the star image based on the ROW amount.

Comment: mysql_num_rows will return the number of rows in a SELECT result. So, if you get back two rows, you'll output two images. This is not how a "normal" ratings script works; rather, you'll read the rating from a single table row, and output stars based on that. Or, some will take the average over a number of rows, and print a number of stars based on the floating result.

Comment: Oh, ofc yes. I don't know what I've been thinking of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then i think, all you need to do is fetch the rating (i.e. a number) from the database and just use that number directly to display the number of stars. Coz mysql_rows_count would give you the total number of records in a result set which is returned as a result of a select query on multiple columns, but in your case you only need to access one column which would contain the rating and another column which would probably contain user id or some sort of key to associate the ratings with. The result set can be fetched as an associative array which can then be used by indices to fetch the right column. Have a look at this: [PHP-mysql_fetch_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) .

EDIT: just to sum up (not the actual syntax) :

```
$array = mysql_fetch_array(<your select query fetching only the needed columns>);

$images = $array[0] // assuming the rating number is at the 0th index

//image display code, do your stuff
```

Comment: I used a for() loop, as I wrote in my answer to this question. Very easy :o)

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I did:

I had the numbers from 1-5 in my database in a row called 'rating'. Now when I picked this out of the database I stuffed the number (1-5) into a variable called '$starRating'.

```
for($i=1;$i<=$starRating;$i++){
echo "<span class='star'><span class='starText'>$i</span></span>";
}
```

Then I created a class called star and starText:

```
.star{
width:18px;
height:18px;
background:url('../images/design/smallImg/star.png') no-repeat;
text-align:center;
float:right;
margin-top:2px;
}

/* star content */
.starText{
    display:none;
}
```

.starText is made to hide the text that would've been from the for() loop. 
*** I don't know if you can avoid the text another way around ***

This works for me perfectly. 
I wrote this to help people searching for an easy solution to this.